# using pyd files outside python

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-construction, pyd

i am working on a compiler maker that compiles python code into other languages (similar to LLVM). since the compiler doesn't actually use the intreperter, just the actual file, i don't know what to do with .pyd and .pyc files. i thought about working on the currently existing python uncompiler to make it work with python3. but idk what to do with .pyd files. the only thing i know about them is that they work like a DLL file but for python, and that it's possible to compile languages like rust or java into .pyd files. so can anyone tell me what can i do to compile or use .pyd files outside of pure python code, for something like javascript or rust?

Comment: Related: [Python docs - Is a *.pyd file the same as a DLL?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html#is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll). `.pyd` _are_ DLL files, just with some requirements as to what's in them.